# Runtime Warning: This channel is already in use

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I am writing a code for Ultrasonic distance sensor. I have wired all the things perfectly and written the code for it but somehow it gives a runtime error of the channel already being in use. Below is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

def distance(measure = 'cm'):
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
    gpio.setup(12, gpio.OUT)   #Here it gives error of channel in use
    gpio.setup(16, gpio.IN)    

    gpio.output(12, False)     #it doesn't show me any value of distance
    while(gpio.input(16) == 0):
        nosig = time.time()

    while(gpio.input(16) == 1):
        sig = time.time()

    t = sig - nosig

    if(measure == 'cm'):
        distance = t / 0.000058
    elif(measure == 'in'):
        distance = t / 0.000148
    else:
        print('improper measurement: inches or centimeters')
        distance = None

    gpio.cleanup()
    return distance()

print(distance('cm'))
```

Comment: In future please post 'proper' code, without the pointed arrows at the start of the line. You probably copied this in IDLE. Much better to use a text editor / IDE instead of the IDLE interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're running `gpio.setup()` on that pin every time you call that function. You need to run `setmode` and `setup` once, and then just check the distance in the function.

```
gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(12, gpio.OUT)   #Here it gives error of channel in use
gpio.setup(16, gpio.IN) 

def distance(measure = 'cm'):
    gpio.output(12, False)
    ...
```

You might find it easier to use gpiozero's [DistanceSensor](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#distance-sensor-hc-sr04) class instead.

Comment: No, the program should run atleast once but, when i run it it executes but doesn't show any values of distance. I don't know whether it's because of GPIO pin issue or something else but, the sensor doesn't seem to be receiving the input somehow.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan - well, you still need to move the setup code outside the function def, so that it will only be run once. As Ben says: the error you get is a result of the repeated init calls. Debugging can continue after you corrected that.